# Memory Leak with vector of primitive values

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have a class that has vectors of primitive values with a memory leak and I can't see it.  It used to wrap a map and had more functionality but the map was leaking even more.  Can someone explain where and why this is happening?

I'm doing this in XCode and using the XCode leak detector.  The objects are allocated at

```
    this->values.push_back(range.at(idx));
```

*SimpleMap.hpp*

```
class SimpleMap
{
private:
    long offset = 0;
    
public:
    SimpleMap() {};
    ~ SimpleMap();
    
    vector<double> indexVals;
    vector<double> values;
    double value(double at);
    void clear();
    void createMapFromIndices(shared_ptr<vector<long>> indices, vector<long> &range);
};
```

*SimpleMap.cpp*

```
double SimpleMap::value(double at)
{
    long idx = at - offset;
    if (this->indexVals.at(idx) == at)
    {
        return this->values.at(idx);
    }
    throw BoundaryException("No value at Index");
}

SimpleMap::~SimpleMap()
{
    this->clear();
}

void SimpleMap::clear()
{
    this->indexVals.clear();
    this->indexVals.shrink_to_fit();
    this->values.clear();
    this->values.shrink_to_fit();
}

void SimpleMap::createMapFromIndices(shared_ptr<vector<long>> indices, vector<long> &range)
{
    this->clear();
    this->offset = indices->front();
        
    for (long idx: *indices)
    {
        this->indexVals.push_back(idx);
        this->values.push_back(range.at(idx));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your posted code looks clean to me. What makes you think that your program is leaking memory? You need to provide a [mcve] and any data that shows there is a memory leak. The leak could be somewhere else in your program too but it's hard to tell from the posted code.

Comment: Other than doing redundant clearing at the destructor, and passing a `shared_ptr` where a reference would do, there seems to be nothing wrong.  Most likely the code using `SimpleMap` is the culprit. How do you construct instances of `SimpleMap`

Comment: I wish I had a simple answer for how I construct these but your comments are helpful. At least I know i'm probably looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Thank you both. I was constructing SimpleMap on the stack in one case.  When I changed that it cured about 40% of my leaks.  I removed the method createMapFromIndices and simply made it a constructor.

Comment: @RobertSchmid it does not seem that it cured your issues. How do you construct the object on the stack? Can you show the line?

Comment: @RobertSchmid how do you know that it was leaking??

Comment: try running Valgrind for memory leak

Comment: @MichaelVeksler. I only cured one instance of it but it revealed the broader scope of the problem in the process.  I have an overly complex object structure with shared_ptrs of objects containing shared pointers of objects and copies are getting in.  I've been too long away from worrying about my own garbage collection and I'm treating shared_ptrs like they are java.

Comment: @RobertSchmid in C++, unlike Java, object construction is done without `new`. With c++14, and later, you almost never have to manage pointers manually, as the language does it all for you. Just use containers, sometimes you'd call `std::make_unique`, even less `std::make_shared`. If you don't have c++14, only c++11, you don't have make_unique, you should still create unique_ptr (unfortunately with `new`). And even with pre-c++11, you still don't need new/delete that often, and mostly construct containers (without `new`)